# Kubuntu 20.04 task manager blue shadow

Tags: kubuntu, visual-artifacts

Kubuntu 20.04.1
integrated video card AMD Stoney R2

When i hold the cursor over the task manager a blue shadow appears and when i move the cursor to another position this blue shadow disappears.

My question is whether this problem is common or not ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System Settings` then to
`Workspace Behavior` / `Desktop effects`
and uncheck `Screen edge`
resulting in removing the blue shadow from the task manager.

Comment: This also solve another issue where the WHOLE screen has a blue overlay!